# Bundler Error when attempting Capistrano Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, capistrano3, ubuntu-20.04

I am attempting to deploy a ruby on rails web app to a staging server but continue to get the error:  bundle stderr: /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

I have attempted to install bundler on the server directly, and even after doing so it continues to fail with the same error.  Full error log and deploy.rb below.

Full Log:

```
   % cap staging deploy
[Deprecation Notice] Future versions of Capistrano will not load the Git SCM
plugin by default. To silence this deprecation warning, add the following to
your Capfile after `require "capistrano/deploy"`:

    require "capistrano/scm/git"
    install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

deploy@00.000.000.000's password:
rvm 1.29.10 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
ruby-2.7.0
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/tmp
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.313s
      Uploading /home/deploy/tmp/git-ssh-Myapp-staging-marcuselmer.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /home/deploy/tmp/git-ssh-Myapp-staging-marcuselmer.sh
    ✔ 02 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.276s
00:01 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:.../myApp.git HEAD
      01 123abad2c0a3f9fa670259253608e11086661c6b   HEAD
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 1.653s
00:02 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.278s
00:03 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/log /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/app…
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.319s
00:03 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/config
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.274s
00:04 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/repo
00:05 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:.../myApp.git
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.314s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
      02 From bitbucket.org:.../myApp
      02    01e45c6b..123abad2  master     -> master
    ✔ 02 deploy@00.000.000.000 1.901s
00:07 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.312s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246
    ✔ 02 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.924s
00:09 deploy:set_current_revision
      01 echo "123abad2c0a3f9fa670259253608e11086661c6b" >> REVISION
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.269s
00:09 deploy:symlink:linked_files
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/config
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.317s
      02 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/config/secrets.yml /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/config/secrets.yml
    ✔ 02 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.277s
00:11 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246 /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/tmp /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases…
    ✔ 01 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.307s
      02 rm -rf /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/log
    ✔ 02 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.269s
      03 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/log /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/log
    ✔ 03 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.335s
      04 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/tmp/pids
    ✔ 04 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.272s
      05 rm -rf /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/tmp/cache
    ✔ 05 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.318s
      06 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/tmp/cache
    ✔ 06 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.283s
      07 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/tmp/sockets
    ✔ 07 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.308s
      08 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/vendor/bundle
    ✔ 08 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.277s
      09 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/public/system /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/public/system
    ✔ 09 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.314s
      10 ln -s /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/public/assets
    ✔ 10 deploy@00.000.000.000 0.268s
00:19 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
      01 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by y…
      01 To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
      01 To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`
      01    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
      01    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'
      01    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
      01    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@00.000.000.000: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@00.000.000.000: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [9486807a] Finished in 0.308 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [5d323bc9] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check --path /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle as deploy@00.000.000.000

 DEBUG [5d323bc9] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check --path /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle

 DEBUG [5d323bc9]   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.

To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

 DEBUG [5d323bc9] Finished in 0.648 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [38f3d295] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@00.000.000.000

 DEBUG [38f3d295] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

 DEBUG [38f3d295]   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (1.16.1) required by your /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/releases/20201230174246/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.

To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:1.16.1`

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:294:in `activate_bin_path'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle:30:in `<main>'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'

    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.10.1"

set :application, "Myapp"
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:…/myApp.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/apps/myApp

set :linked_files, %w{config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :tmp_dir, "/home/deploy/tmp"
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] if ENV['BRANCH']
set :user, "deploy"


# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do
    task :start do
        invoke 'bin/delayed_job:start'
    end
    desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
            execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
        end
    end

    after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
    after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

Server Info:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
```

Bundler is confirmed to be installed on the server.

[Gem Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSdxd.png)

Do I perhaps need to change the default version of bundler?

I can see the release folders get generated, but because of the failure no current sym_link is ever created and deployment fails.  Is there a server setup step I'm missing for the initial cap deploy to a new staging server?  Do I need to have bundler installed in a specific server location in order for cap to "find" it?

Comment: You need to run `gem install bundler` and apparently in your case `gem install bundler -v '1.16.1'`. This needs to be run on the server you are deploying to

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thanks for the quick response.  I've actually attempted that already, I've even done so with sudo to maybe see if it was an access issue and it appears to have no impact.  Do I need to run the install at specific level on the server?  I've tried it at the home level, the app level, and even at the release level (which works, but doesn't really solve the issue since I would have to run it every time a new release folder is created).

Comment: @engineersmnky - I need to apologize, it would appear that all those times I thought I had installed bundler may not have been successful.  I'm getting fun ipv6 vs ipv4 issues with downloading the gem, but that's a separate issue.  Once I wrap that issue up I'll retry installing bundler as you recommend.

Comment: @engineersmnky - I have installed bundler but continue to get the same message.  What am I missing?  I also noticed that with each deploy it creates a new folder in releases, and it's like it can't find bundler in that specific release, but since a new folder is created with each deploy I can't "proactively install" bundler on a folder that doesn't yet exist.  I'm kind of at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past this blocker.  The ultimate issue is that I had to log into the correct shell and run gem install bundler:1.16.1.

In order to log into the bash I used this command:
/bin/bash --login

Then run gem install:
gem install bundler:1.16.1